# How do I represent words numerically such that similar words have numbers close to each other

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, word2vec

I have to implement a Machine Learning algorithm, specifically, Linear regression, using features that include both text (usually one word) and numbers.

How do I represent words numerically such that words that are similar are represented by numbers that are closer to each other than numbers for words that are dissimilar.

Example:-

log4j1.2rc1   -> 60

log4j2.8      -> 61

struts1.3.10  -> 90

I checked out **Word2Vec** but it requires training the model with a large number of words before using it. My constraint is that I do not know all the words and I will only receive them like a stream.

**Update:** OK, I'm just going to say it, the '*words*' are going to be various features of software libraries like, library names, filenames, paths, etc. Given a file, the ML algorithm has to identify what library it belongs to.

Comment: A linear regression on non-numerical data is a complete nonsense.

Comment: How do you define closeness between 2 words?  Alphabetical ordering?  Levenshtein distance?  word2vec won't work for word lists because it learns the grammar of the documents you are training on; i.e. how each word behaves as part of the language.  The results from word2vec trained on an English corpus would have very similar vectors for "good" and "bad" because they have very similar grammatical usage in English.

Comment: @James - In my case closeness is defined by similarity in sequence of characters.in the word (not going so deep as semantic similarity).

Comment: As @James said, Levenshtein distance is the algorithm you are looking for. Ofcourse, it will not cover synonymns or slangs or acronymns etc...

Comment: Take a look at the Python [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy) library.